# How to remove special ASCII characters?

Tags: sas

I am trying to remove special character from the string.

"Mumbai rains live updates: IMD predicts heavy rainfall for next 24 hours �"

```
data demo1 (keep=headline2 headline3 headline4 headline5);
set kk.newspaper_append_freq_daily1;
headline2=trim(headline);
headline3=tranwrd(headline2,"�"," ");
headline5=compress(headline2,"�");
headline4=index(headline2,"�");
run;
```

Comment: Doesn't ````tranwrd```` and ````compress```` give you the desired results in this case? I would expect them to. If you want to remove all special characters I would use ````compress```` with the 'k' option as appropriate. Another option is the ````translate```` function

Comment: � indicates to our users where we have lost some of their text data due to mishandling it, most likely by decoding with the wrong character encoding. Try solving that problem instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [kpropdata](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/nlsref/61893/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003285543.htm) function.
From doc:

> Removes or converts unprintable characters.

Code example:

```
%let in=kk.newspaper_append_freq_daily1;
%let out=demo1;

data &out; 
set &in; 
array cc (*) _character_; 
do i=1 to dim(cc); 
 cc(_N_)=kpropdata(cc(i),"TRUNC", 'utf-8'); 
 end; 
run;
```

In code I've used [array](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000201956.htm) statement to iterate over all character columns in table.

Answer (score 1):

`compress` should also handle this if you keep a whitelist of characters rather than trying to exclude a blacklist - e.g.

```
clean_text = compress(dirty_text,'','kw');
```

The `k` modifier keeps characters instead of removing them, and `w` adds all printable characters to the list.